# Mathematica "linked lists" and performance

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

In Mathematica, I create singly linked lists like so:

```
toLinkedList[x_List] := Fold[pair[#2, #1] &, pair[], Reverse[x]];

fromLinkedList[ll_pair] := List @@ Flatten[ll];

emptyQ[pair[]] := True;
emptyQ[_pair] := False;
```

Using the symbol `pair` for the cons cells has the advantage of `Flatten` working safely even if the lists contain Mathematica-style `List`s, and allows you to define custom notation using `MakeExpression`/`MakeBoxes`, which makes everything much more pleasant. In order to avoid having to muck around with [`$IterationLimit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$IterationLimit.html), I wrote functions to work with these lists using either `While` loops or `NestWhile` instead of using recursion. Naturally, I wanted to see which approach would be faster, so I wrote two candidates so I could watch 'em fight:

```
nestLength[ll_pair] := 
 With[{step = {#[[1, -1]], #[[-1]] + 1} &},
  Last@NestWhile[step, {ll, 0}, ! emptyQ@First@# &]];

whileLength[ll_pair] := 
 Module[{result = 0, current = ll},
  While[! emptyQ@current,
   current = current[[2]];
   ++result];
  result];
```

The results were very strange. I tested the functions on linked lists of length 10000, and `whileLength` was usually about 50% faster, at about 0.035 seconds to `nestLength`'s 0.055 seconds. However, occasionally `whileLength` would take about ~4 seconds. I thought there might be some caching behavior, so I started generating fresh, random lists to check, and `whileLength` wouldn't necessarily be slow on the first run with a new list; it might take dozens of times to see the slowdown, but then it wouldn't recur (at least not for the 200 runs I was trying with each list).

What might be going on?

For reference, the function I used for testing is this:

```
getTimes[f_, n_] :=
 With[{ll = toLinkedList@RandomInteger[100, 10000]},
  Table[Timing[f@ll], {n}][[All, 1]]]
```

**EDIT:** I neglected to mention the version earlier; I got these results with Mathematica 8.

**EDIT the second:** When  I read [Daniel Lichtblau's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095505/mathematica-linked-lists-and-performance/5113303#5113303), I realized that my times for "typical" runs omitted a leading 0. It's been fixed.

**EDIT the third:** I think [Leonid Shifrin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095505/mathematica-linked-lists-and-performance/5098148#5098148) is correct to associate the issue with `Module`; I can get the same sort of behavior from the `NestWhile`-based version by replacing the `With` with a `Module`:

```
nestModuleLength[ll_pair] := 
  Module[{step = {#[[1, -1]], #[[-1]] + 1} &}, 
   Last@NestWhile[step, {ll, 0}, ! emptyQ@First@# &]];

In[15]:= Select[getTimes[nestModuleLength, 100], # > 3 &]
Out[15]= {3.797}
```

Comment: Developer'PackedArrayQ may be relevant

Comment: @Yaroslav Bulatov: I can't see why packed arrays would be relevant, since nothing should be packed except the initial `List` generated by `RandomInteger`, which is immediately converted into a tree-like expression.

Comment: Are you using version 7 or 8? Regardless, for what it's worth, I think you've uncovered something of a bug or at least a soft spot in the evaluation behavior.

Comment: I can't take the credit for `Module`- @belisarius was the first to suggest that it was the culprit.

Comment: It is not With or Module per se (and I believe I even reproduced the problem with Block). It is that there are collisions between symbols that fool the evaluator into thinking it needs to check whether expressions require reevaluation.

Comment: FWIW, a naive translation of this code to F# is shorter and between 300 and 30,000x faster than Mathematica: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8286376/13924

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The examples below give typical results.

One slow example in a length 20 run.

```
In[18]:= getTimes[whileLength, 20]

Out[18]= {0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, \
0.031, 0.047, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 3.547, 0.047, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, \
0.031, 0.031}
```

I note in passing that the timings are ~10x faster than in the original post, except for the slow cases which are comparable. Not sure what accounts for that difference in ratios.

No slow examples.

```
In[17]:= getTimes[nestLength, 20]

Out[17]= {0.047, 0.047, 0.062, 0.047, 0.047, 0.062, 0.047, 0.047, \
0.047, 0.063, 0.046, 0.047, 0.047, 0.063, 0.047, 0.046, 0.047, 0.063, \
0.047, 0.047}
```

One slow example in a length 100 run.

```
In[19]:= getTimes[whileLength, 100]

Out[19]= {0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 3.594, 0.047, 0.031, \
0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.047, 0.031, \
0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.047, 0.031, 0.031, \
0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.047, 0.031, \
0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.047, 0.031, \
0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.047, 0.031, 0.031, \
0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.047, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, \
0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.046, 0.032, \
0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.031, 0.047, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, \
0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, 0.047, 0.031, 0.031, 0.031, 0.032, 0.031, \
0.031, 0.031}
```

Mathematica implements, imperfectly, what is called "infinite evaluation". That is to say, an expression reevaluates until it stops changing. To make this reasonably fast there are various optimizations that attempt to short circuit the process whenever possible.

In some cases this can be tricky to discern (due to an effect similar to hash collisions), and expressions might be needlessly reevaluated. Deeply nested expressions tend to be a worst case for this. We have further code that will often address these even in cases of collisions.

The culprit in this instance is exactly this code that attempts to determine quickly whether an expression requires reevaluation. It is peculiar but possibly a clue (to someone) that this happens at most once in a run inside that While loop. So something happens in the bad cases that prevents recurrence whilst inside the same While.

At one time I was familiar with the reevaluation detection code, having written a chunk of it. But it was rewritten for version 8. So even after seeing this suboptimal behavior in a debugger, it is is something of a mystery to me. About all I can say right now is that I filed a bug report.

As Leonid Shifrin observed, symbols with Attribute of HoldAllComplete are immune to this problem. So using that attribute can be beneficial for this type of code.

Daniel Lichtblau
Wolfram Research

Comment: Just FYI. I was trying to repro the behavior running under the Workbench to profile it. But it just run flawless!

Comment: @belisarius Was this version 8.0? That could in theory make a difference. Beyond that, I am flummoxed. (Not sure what that means exactly, but I suspect it has to do with being beaten over the head by a flumm ox. At leas that's how it feels, some days.) Also, if you changed names of things e.g. pair-->flair, that could cause a collision to disappear.

Comment: @belisarius This might elicit the bad behavior. In getTimes change last line to Table[Update[]; Timing[f@ll], {n}][[All, 1]]

Comment: Yes, version 8. I'll try the Update[] thing and come back with results.

Answer (score 7):

A disclaimer: the following is a speculation. This seems to be related to the search for `UpValues`. It looks like this has been optimized for global variables (so that the system skips this step when it can determine that it can do that), but not for `Module` - generated local variables. To test this, assign `HoldAllComplete` attribute to `pair`, and the effect disappears (since then, `UpValues` are not checked for `current`):

```
SetAttributes[pair, HoldAllComplete];

In[17]:= ll = toLinkedList@RandomInteger[100, 10000];
Max[Table[Timing[whileLength[ll]], {1000}][[All, 1]]]

Out[18]= 0.047
```

HTH

Comment: "since then, UpValues are not checked for current"; can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @acl: when evaluator meets expression `f[a]` and `f` has a `HoldAllComplete` attribute, not only is `a` not evaluated before `f` (what happens to `a` then entirely depends of the rules for `f`), but also `UpValues` associated with `a` are not checked, while they are checked when `f` has `HoldAll`. I am not completely sure that this is what plays a role here, but the r.h.s of an assignment looks like `Part[pair[num,pair[..]],2]`. When `Part` is evaluated, `pair[...]` is evaluated (search for `UpValues` of the form `pair[___,element,___]`), but not if  `pair` is `HoldAllComplete`.

Comment: @acl: This was known as an "in-place" list modification problem in version 3, but seems to have been optimized in later versions (David Wagner has a discussion on this in his book, Chapter 7, p.211). My guess was that the optimization for in-place list (expression) modifications did not cover (or covered incompletely) the case of local variables generated by `Module`. As I said, I may well be wrong, this is just a guess.

Answer (score 4):

Seems it's related to the Module local symbols memory management.

I'll show the timing series from some runs. Each run gives of course a unique Plot, but I checked "consistency" among runs. Look:

```
whileLength[l2_pair] := 
  Module[{result = 0}, current = l2; 
   While[! emptyQ@current, current = current[[2]];
    ++result];
   result];
```

gives the following Timing series:

[image]

While using only Global symbols:

```
whileLength[l2_pair] := 
  Module[{}, result = 0; current = l2; 
   While[! emptyQ@current, current = current[[2]];
    ++result];
   result];
```

gives:

[image]