# Why does mathematica kernel crash when I access my linked list?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm using mathematica 7, and I'm trying to use a singly linked list (~50,000 elements) to avoid using AppendTo in a dynamic list to increase speed. 
In this test, I can create a list of 10 elements as follows

```
list1 = Fold[{#1, #2} &, {}, RandomInteger[10^5, 10]]
```

And I try to access it with `Part` like this (accessing a random element 100 times)

```
Timing[list1[[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[1, #], 2]] & /@RandomInteger[{1,10}, 100]]
```

This works fine for small lists (10 as above).  For reasons I don't understand, this kills the kernel when the list has more elements (like 10^4).  I've tried looking around on this site & elsewhere, but just can't figure out how I should be using the linked list.  I've even tried to use different implementations like `f[e1,f[e2,f[e3,...f[]...]]]` but I don't know a nice way to access & manipulate elements when using this scheme. I imagine the problem has to do w/ `$RecursionLimit` but I don't know how to get around it.

In particular I'd like to be able to use

```
list1[[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[1, index], 2]] = new value
```

in my code. Again, this works when the list is small but crashes the kernel eventually for larger lists.  What's weird is that the kernel doesn't crash always, but only stochastically for large lists.  This sounds similar to something that was described [here on SE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095505/mathematica-linked-lists-and-performance), but I don't know if that discussion is relevant. Really I just need help in modifying LL elements & using LL correctly in mathematica.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks @Mr.Wizard. using Bag lets me avoid the crashes. Do you know what causes this crash? The machine that I was using runs OSX and has 2GB RAM. If I could figure out a way to make the linked list work, I could compare its timing to `Bag`

Comment: No, I do not know why it crashes, but I'll suppose that the system was simply not designed for doing `Part` assignments at a depth of hundreds of thousands.  `Bag` is used internally to avoid just such situations.  It also performs ***much*** better.  On my system merely extracting ten random elements from the linked list with five million elements takes about one second.  Using ``Internal`BagPart`` I can extract about 26 *million* random parts in the same time from a `Bag` of equal length, so `Bag` is some six orders of magnitude faster in this case!

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm the crash, but only with a significantly deeper `Part` specification:

```
n = 5000000;

list1 = Fold[List, {}, RandomInteger[10^5, n]];

Do[
 list1[[Sequence @@ ConstantArray[1, i], 2]] = "token"; Print[i],
 {i, 100000, 200000, 10000}
]
```

> 100000 110000 120000 130000 140000 150000 160000 170000

So on my system the crash happens with a depth somewhere over 170,000.  It also happens, at least at this depth, only when assigning a part rather than merely extracting one:

```
Timing[
 list1[[##, 2]] & @@ ConstantArray[1, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, n - 1}, 10]
]
```

> ```
> {1.03, {77041, 74008, 29990, 13286, 12762, 48702, 76027, 25009, 31267, 1887}}
> ```

---

## Recommendation

As an alternative I propose using the [`` Internal` `` `*Bag*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762/618728).

```
n = 5000000;

list2 = Internal`Bag @ RandomInteger[10^5, n];  (* fill our Bag *)

Internal`StuffBag[list2, 27182];  (* add an element to the Bag *)

Internal`BagLength @ list2  (* check the length of our Bag *)
```

> ```
> 5000001
> ```

```
pos = RandomInteger[{1, n}, 10];  (* pick ten random positions *)

(* assign to those positions values 1 through 10 *)
MapIndexed[
  (Internal`BagPart[list2, #] = #2[[1]]) &,
  pos
];

Internal`BagPart[list2, pos]  (* check the contents of those positions *)
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

```
(* convert our Bag into a standard list *)
flat = Internal`BagPart[list2, All];

flat[[pos]]  (* check the contents again *)
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
> ```

```
Last @ flat  (* check that the element we appended is still there *)
```

> ```
> 27182
> ```

Comment: Is this a candidate for migration? Good question for [mathematica.se], but it is on topic here.

Comment: @rcollyer flag if you want to; I had a civil disagreement with one S.O. moderator over what should or should not be migrated, so I'm not flagging anything here for migration now.